# Putting binary resources (images) in a separate assembly (WPF/.NET)

Tags: .net, wpf, image, resources

I have a .NET solution with a couple of projects. The output is a WPF application. Now I would like to put my binary resources (images/icons) in a single project/assembly in this solution, so that all my other projects in can use them.

My question is how I can do that? What type of project should I create and how should I reference these resources in my XAML code (in the other projects)?

I've tried quite a few things but I can't seem to get it to work...

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to put them in a resource files (resx) within visual studio. If you want to access them from outside the project, you can make the resource public or internal, or you can wrap it in a property.